# Issue to add upload image in wordpress media library

Tags: wordpress

i have write code to upload file in folder and in wordpress media library.
   file is going to upload in wordpress folder but issues it is not moving in media library.

function fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

```
    $uploadUrl= wp_get_upload_dir();

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return FALSE;

        $rel = $_POST['relation'];

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'fname_'. $rel, $_POST['fname'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'mname_'.$rel, $_POST['mname'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'lname_'. $rel, $_POST['lname'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'relation', $_POST['relation'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'bod_'. $rel, $_POST['bod'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'education_'.$rel ,$_POST['education'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'occupation_'. $rel, $_POST['occupation'] );

    // update_user_meta( $user_id, 'picture_'. $rel, $uploadUrl['url']."/".$_POST['picture'] );

    if($_FILES['picture']['name'] != ''){
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['picture'];
    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
    $imageurl = "";
    if ( $movefile && ! isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
       $imageurl = $movefile['url'];
       echo "url : ".$imageurl;

       update_user_meta( $user_id, 'picture_'. $rel, $_FILES['picture']['name'] );
    } else {
       echo $movefile['error'];
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the file as attachment:

```
        // Save to media library
        $filename = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
        $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
        $attachment = array(
           'guid' => $imageurl,
           'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
           'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
           'post_content' => '',
           'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file );
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
        $res1= wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

So basically, your code will look something like this:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );
function fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    $uploadUrl = wp_get_upload_dir();

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
            return FALSE;

            $rel = $_POST['relation'];

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'fname_'. $rel, $_POST['fname'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'mname_'.$rel, $_POST['mname'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'lname_'. $rel, $_POST['lname'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'relation', $_POST['relation'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'bod_'. $rel, $_POST['bod'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'education_'.$rel ,$_POST['education'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'occupation_'. $rel, $_POST['occupation'] );

    // update_user_meta( $user_id, 'picture_'. $rel, $uploadUrl['url']."/".$_POST['picture'] );

    if($_FILES['picture']['name'] != ''){
        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['picture'];
        $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

        $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
        $imageurl = "";
        if ( $movefile && ! isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
             $imageurl = $movefile['url'];


                // Save to media library
                $filename = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
                $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
                $attachment = array(
                   'guid' => $imageurl,
                   'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                   'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
                   'post_content' => '',
                   'post_status' => 'inherit'
                );
                $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file );
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
                $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
                $res1= wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );


             echo "url : ".$imageurl;

             update_user_meta( $user_id, 'picture_'. $rel, $_FILES['picture']['name'] );
        } else {
             echo $movefile['error'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not Working this code. I had done some changes in thi,  now it's working good. Thanks for this code.

Comment: Hi @Mahen if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: I don't think you could just take any code from the internet and it would work out of the box, any code will need you to implement it to your own case.

Answer (score 1):

I got @Ali_k answer working by changing those two '$file' variables to be like this:

```
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $user_id );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $movefile['file'] );
```

Comment: Yes true, but you also have to use: `wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $movefile['file'], $user_id )`  to make everything work correctly